# Load particular bean using Spring SPEL method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-config

I have a requirement to load specific bean on a condition which i am reading from config properties . 
I have two beans so i am trying to load it as below

```
public interface MediatorInt {

public void init();

}

class A implements MediatorInt {
        init() { It does some task }
    }

class B implements MediatorInt {
    init(){ It does some task }
}

public class MasterNewGenImpl {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("config")
    private Configuration config;

    @Autowired
    MediatorInt mediatorInt;

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    public void startService() {
        mediatorInt.init();
    }
}

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ca"/>
    <bean id="config" class="com.ca.configuration.ConfigImplementation"/>    
    <bean id="masterSlave" class="com.ca.masterslave.A"/>
    <bean id="systemState" class="com.ca.masterslave.B"/>
    <bean id="masterSlaveNewGen" class="com.ca.masterslave.MasterNewGenImpl">
    <property name = "mediatorInt" value="#{config.getMediatorMode() == 'true' ? 'systemState' : 'masterSlave'}" />
</bean>
```

But the bean is not getting loaded .

Can you please help if any error in the syntax or the method of using it .

Comment: Is it not loading anything in mediatorInt or you are getting unexpected object in mediatorInt ? Also, try removing @Autowired from mediatorInt.

Comment: Thanks for the responding . I am getting unexpected object in mediatorInt

Comment: i tried removing @Autowired from mediatorInt.Again there is same error Unexpected method call MediatorMasterSlaveInt.init() .

Comment: if `config.getMediatorMode()` returns boolean, try `value="#{ config.getMediatorMode() ? ...`

Comment: i have tried . Still the issue remain the same .Getting the same exception